# Suspending IO-bound and CPU-bound functions in Kotlin's coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Executing an IO-bound function (say, requesting data from a backend) in a coroutine gives me the advantage of suspending it's execution until the result of the request becomes available, right? However, a CPU-bound function (parsing a huge text file, for example) doesn't 'wait' for anything, it just does a lot of work. So, does executing it inside a coroutine NOT give me the advantage of suspending its execution? The only (valuable) advantage coroutines give me when it comes to CPU-bound functions is being able to choose the thread (or pool of threads) that will be blocked while executing the function, am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

> So, does executing it inside a coroutine NOT give me the advantage of suspending its execution?

I am not sure I understand what you mean by that, but calling a suspending function will suspend the calling coroutine anyway, whatever dispatcher you choose, and that doesn't depend on what's inside the function as far as I know.

However, please note that calling a *blocking* function from inside a coroutine will make this coroutine block the thread executing it, there is no magic here. That's why blocking operations should be avoided inside coroutines.

> The only (valuable) advantage coroutines give me when it comes to CPU-bound functions is being able to choose the thread (or pool of threads) that will be blocked while executing the function, am I correct?

Using `Dispachers.IO` or `Dispatchers.Default` only has the effect of choosing a different pool of threads, yes.

In case of `IO`, the pool will spawn as many threads as necessary, because they can all be "blocked on I/O".

In case of `Default`, only a number of threads proportional to the number of cores will ever be created, because there would be no point for CPU-bound tasks to create more threads than cores (if all the cores are busy, then context switching can only degrade the overall performance).

Comment: My mental model of coroutines is still quite muddy, I'm sorry, @Joffrey. What is the advantage I get if I simply write 'suspend' in the declaration of a CPU-bound function and call it inside a `launch(Dispatchers.Unconfined)`? Is it any different than doing the same to an IO-bound function?

Comment: @bernardo.g I'm not an expert of the `Unconfined` dispatcher, but it is discouraged unless you have a very specific use case. AFAIU, it makes the coroutine start in the current thread until the first suspension point, and then resumes in a possibly different thread depending on the called suspending function. This means that the beginning of your coroutine is guaranteed to execute right away.

Comment: @bernardo.g However, if the first thing you do is calling your CPU-bound suspending function, this is a suspension point, and I imagine your function is likely to be executed in another thread, but I don't know enough to be sure of that. So IMO, I don't think there is any "advantage" in doing what you described here, and I don't think there is a difference with doing this with an IO bound functoin, other than the fact that the IO bound function might block the thread it's called on.

Answer (score 2):

suspend functions do not automatically make the function as not blocking the thread, like in the following case as it would still block the calling thread ( dispatcher associated with the scope used to launch the coroutine)

```
suspend fun findBigPrime(): BigInteger = 
    BigInteger.probablePrime(4096, Random())
```

suspend functions can be made into a non-blocking thread function by using withContext like the following,

```
suspend fun findBigPrime(): BigInteger =
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        BigInteger.probablePrime(4096, Random())
    }
```

This causes coroutine launched from main/caller thread to be blocking but not the thread itself to be blocking.

https://medium.com/@elizarov/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761